# How to package Trigger.io app for web without deploying to Heroku?

Tags: trigger.io

In the Trigger.io [documentation](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/web.html?highlight=heroku) it states: "Your generated web app can be deployed to any node.js platform. To make deployment really easy, we've added an option to deploy the app directly to Heroku with a single command."

It appears that deploying to Heroku is not optional.  We've got our own nodejs hosting solution and we would like to package our web app for release without the Heroku deployment step.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in `development/web` after you've run the web target, you'll find an Express app.

Your app won't quite work as static files because we need to proxy `forge.request` calls to side step same-origin policy issues, but that Node app should be a good starting point.

Comment: I am specifically looking to avoid the step of deploying to Heroku.  Are you suggesting that for building a production web package we simply "forge build web" and then deploy the dev build for production use?  I am concerned the development build might be unsuitable for production use.  Thank you!

Comment: Yep, exactly - you can use the files from release/web/heroku if you prefer: the only difference is the git repo the release folder. There are no debugging data left in the development folder.